# where can i find the sources for the sample() function in base

Tags: r

i.e. the function that R is calling when it

```
x[.Internal(sample(length(x), size, replace, prob))]
```

thanks in advance;

Comment: see `?.Internal` for more information.

Comment: You might be interested in a nice R News article that Uwe Ligges wrote a while back, on "Accessing the Sources". It's on page 43 of [the pdf at this link](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up `do_sample` in `/trunk/src/main/random.c` from, e.g. the [svn](https://svn.r-project.org/R) repository.

Comment: and you can find that `sample` points to `do_sample` by looking in `/src/main/names.c`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich (+1) Yep, I forgot to talk about that.